# AWS Boto show all roles

Tags: boto3

Trying to list all roles in account so I can attach a policy.  I'm reading through the boto3 documentation but I'm not seeing a method to return a collection of roles in an account.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't find it because roles related api is under boto3 IAM.  And typical api access key are not given the rights to deal with IAM.  You need to grant with IAM access to do this.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html

Answer (score 10):

As per your question - you need to attach the policy to the roles.
For that, first, you are getting all the roles from the account.
you may need any of the below two things to attach the policy to the specific role.

- Role Name
- Arn

Below code can help you- I am making a IAM connection and getting the all roles from the account. Since, You will get output in the form of Dicts and Array, you need to extract the arn or name

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id="XXXXX",aws_secret_access_key="YYYYY")
roles = client.list_roles()
Role_list = roles['Roles']
for key in Role_list:
    print(key['RoleName'])
    print(key['Arn'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to other's suggestions, you will need iterating the result if more than 1,000 roles are found. The default is 100 at a time, but you can configure MaxItems up to 1000. It's easier to collect all roles in an array, and process them after all iterations.

```
import boto3
aws_profile = 'YourProfileName'
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_profile)
client = session.client('iam')

roles = []
response = client.list_roles()
roles.extend(response['Roles'])
while 'Marker' in response.keys():
    response = client.list_roles(Marker = response['Marker'])
    roles.extend(response['Roles'])

print('roles found: ' + str(len(roles)))  
for role in roles:
    print(role['RoleName'])
    print(role['Arn'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iam_client =boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'], `enter code here`aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'], `enter code here`aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],)
    role_names=[]
    response = iam_client.list_roles(
                PathPrefix='/',
                MaxItems=80 )
    print(response)
    roles = response['Roles']
    for role in roles:
            print(role['Arn'])
            role_names.append(role['RoleName'])
    if response['IsTruncated']:
        response2=iam_client.list_roles(
                    PathPrefix='/',
                    Marker=response['Marker'],
                    MaxItems=80 )
        roles2 = response2['Roles']
        for role2 in roles2:
                print(role2['Arn'])
                role_names.append(role2['RoleName'])
        print(response2)
    if response2['IsTruncated']:
        response3=iam_client.list_roles(
                    PathPrefix='/',
                    Marker=response2['Marker'],
                    MaxItems=80 )
        roles3 = response3['Roles']
        for role3 in roles3:
                print(role2['Arn'])
                role_names.append(role3['RoleName'])
        print(response3)
    print(role_names)
    clearlist(role_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the API, [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_roles) it is documented.

Example:

```
response = client.list_roles(
    PathPrefix='string',
    Marker='string',
    MaxItems=123
)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Here's what I came up with.  Replace CAPS values with your actual values.

## attach an inline policy to all roles within an account

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author: Nick Skitch 

import boto3
import json


def main():

    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name=PROFILE_NAME)
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    policy_document = get_policy_body(IAM_POLICY_JSON)

    roles = get_roles(client)

    for role in roles:
        update_role(role,client,"required_tags",policy_document)

def get_policy_body(data_file):
    with open(data_file) as data_file:
        data = data_file.read()
    return data

def update_role(role_name, client,iam_policy_name,policy_document):
    response = client.put_role_policy(
    RoleName=role_name,
    PolicyName=iam_policy_name,
    PolicyDocument=policy_document
    )

    print response

def get_roles(client):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    response = None
    role_names = []
    marker = None

    # By default, only 100 roles are returned at a time.
    # 'Marker' is used for pagination.
    while (response is None or response['IsTruncated']):
        # Marker is only accepted if result was truncated.
        if marker is None:
            response = client.list_roles()
        else:
            response = client.list_roles(Marker=marker)

        roles = response['Roles']
        for role in roles:
            print(role['Arn'])
            role_names.append(role['RoleName'])

        if response['IsTruncated']:
            marker = response['Marker']

    return role_names



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```